# Displaying progress bar while intent service is running

Tags: android, service, android-progressbar

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm getting into a muddle.

I start an `IntentService` from my main activity via an `onClick` event, and listen for a response from the service using a `PendingIntent` that references a static inner class `BroadcastReceiver` in the same main activity of the `onClick` event, i.e.,

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);        

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,MyReceiver,0);

    startService(intent);

}

public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // Do stuff here ....
    }
```

Now, all I want to do is show a `ProgressBar` (swirly indeterminate one) on the activity's UI whilst the `IntentService` is doing its stuff. I defined the `ProgressBar` in the xml as

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

I can start it from the `onClick` event by

```
 ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
 pb.setVisibity(View.VISIBLE);
```

But I'm lost as to where and how to hide it??? I can't do it from `myReceiver` as its a static class and I don't have access to the UI. It seems so simple, but I can't figure out the best way. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can figure out two solutions:

1.assign your progressbar to a static reference, and set it to invisible in onReceive

2.make your receiver non-static

Comment: Thanks. Point 1 works. I think the flaw is more in my understanding of static variables (new to android/java). I will have to give them a good read over!

Comment: number 1 can cause memory leak
https://android.jlelse.eu/memory-leak-patterns-in-android-4741a7fcb570

Comment: This Answer makes no sense and is unhelpful. Sorry. There is no code here to show what the OP thinks the solution is.